# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation using a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

This is the first time I am using `CLLocationManager`. I am not sure if i am doing the right thing. Correct me if i am wrong.

I initialize the locationManager in my `viewDidLoad` Method and tell the locationManager to startUpdatingLocation in the same method.

When the delegate receives

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    //do stuff with the coordinates
}
```

to avoid repeated calls to this delegate method.

I have a `UIButton` where users can click to update the location

```
//called by user action
-(IBAction)updateLocation{
    //start updating delegate
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];    
}
```

However when the location changes and when I click the `UIbutton`, the location coordinates donot change at all. :(

What am i doing wrong? Is this the right of doing or should i not stop the locationManager at all ?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: For future reference: Apple's sample code shows how best to do this by calling the delegate multiple times and checking your desired accuracy against the returned location's accuracy: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CLLocationManager` caches your last location and returns it as soon as you call `-startUpdatingLocation`.  So, you are starting updates, receiving the old location, and then stopping updates.

This isn't how `-startUpdatingLocation/-stopUpdatingLocation` are meant to be used.  As I asked above, what's wrong with calling the delegate method multiple times?  If you only want to get the location when the user taps a button, leave the `CLLocationManager` updating, and just check `CLLocationManger`'s `location` property when the user taps your button.

If the reason you're trying to avoid multiple calls to the delegate method is because you're worried about power consumption, etc., adjust the `desiredAccuracy` property of the `CLLocationManager` with something like: `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`.

All told, it might look something like this...

.h file:

```
@interface YourController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationMgr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *lastLocation;

- (IBAction)getNewLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface YourController

@synthesize locationMgr = _locationMgr;
@synthesize lastLocation = _lastLocation;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationMgr.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (!self.lastLocation) {
        self.lastLocation = newLocation;        
    }

    if (newLocation.coordinate.latitude != self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude &&
        newLocation.coordinate.longitude != self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude) {        
        self.lastLocation = newLocation;
        NSLog(@"New location: %f, %f",
              self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude,
              self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        [self.locationMgr stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (IBAction)getNewLocation:(id)sender
{
    [self.locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Old location: %f, %f", 
          self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, 
          self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.locationMgr release];
    self.locationMgr = nil;
    [self.lastLocation release];
    self.lastLocation = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks. So, if i remove stopUpdatingLocation and by that the application will automatically update the location and also when the user taps the button.Am i right ?

Comment: No, the application will automatically *start* updating the location.   I'll edit my answer to show this more clearly...

Comment: And do you want them to also be able to stop location updates?

Comment: That should do it now...all with one button.  Did it in a hurry so may have overlooked something--let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrennonBortz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2231/discussion-between-narayanan-and-brennon-bortz)

Comment: this is exactly my problem...Once i do stopUpdatingLocation the program never actually starts the updating. It just uses the previous coordinate values and never enters the loop again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you have included `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` framework to being with. This is the way you start getting location updates.

```
CLLocationManager *locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationMgr.delegate = self;

[locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

You are correct here. After this you start getting location updates, here in this delegate-

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
   fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // Handle location updates
} 

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Handle error
}
```